# Excel prevent cell and its content from being deleted (no sheet protection)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have 2 columns in my excel sheet which I want to have protected in a way that you can't delete the cell nor its content. I don't want to use the built in sheet protection, instead I want to use VBA (because of no password needed). I found some code which should prevent cells from being deleted, but it doesn't work. Also I have no idea how VBA works and therefore I would be happy if someone can either provide a solution or guide me on how to do it myself.

The code I found is this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A6:B1048576")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo ExitPoint
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not IsDate(Target(1)) Then
        Application.Undo
    End If
ExitPoint:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use sheet protection?

Comment: The Worksheet Change function is only useful if the select one cell.  If they select a range of cells, it will error and quit.  Sheet protection would be better as you can prevent them from selecting the cell in the first place

Comment: I don't want to prevent them the cell from editing. I only want to prevent the users from either deleting the entire cell or removing the entry (no content in the cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to the code in your question, but prevents any cell in columns A:B being deleted / set to blank:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    Dim b As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Terminate

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    For Each c In Target.Cells
        If Not Intersect(c, Range("A:B")) Is Nothing And c.Value = "" Then
            b = True
            GoTo UndoChange
        End If
    Next c

UndoChange:
    If b Then Application.Undo

Terminate:
    If Err Then
        Debug.Print "Error", Err.Number, Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

It works with multiple cell selections, as it loops through each cell in the changed range, and checks for a blank value.

**EDIT:** Amended code, to integrate your existing `Worksheet_Change` functionality;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    Dim b As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Terminate

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    For Each c In Target.Cells
        If Not Intersect(c, Range("A:B")) Is Nothing And c.Value = "" Then
            b = True
            GoTo UndoChange
        End If
        If c.Column = 10 And c.Row >= 6 Then
            c.Value = UCase(c.Value)
        End If
    Next c

UndoChange:
    If b Then Application.Undo

Terminate:
    If Err Then
        Debug.Print "Error", Err.Number, Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: but they are still editable?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried it?

Comment: Can it be that its not possible to have 2 `Worksheet_Change` subs for the same sheet?

Comment: No, you can't. Replace your existing code with the code I posted.

Comment: Well, thats not possible. I would have to merge the code as its other code i need.

Comment: Post your existing code...

Comment: `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J6:J1048576")) Is Nothing Then
         On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
         Application.EnableEvents = False
         Target.Value = UCase(Target)
ErrorHandler:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: Answer edited, to include your existing Worksheet_Change functionality

Comment: its working nearly perfect, besides the fact that i can still shift cells up and therefore delete the cells

Comment: It really would be much easier and more effective to protect the sheet!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65766/discussion-between-xtremebaumer-and-olly).