# How to make data validation with unique formulas in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, data-validation

I am trying to keep the formulas of a worksheet intact, making sure that they will not be removed by a mistake. Using data validation for it.

This is what I am trying:

[image]

It works, **but** the cell content can be deleted with pressing <kbd>delete</kbd> and this is bad. Any solution? Tried `=False` as well, did not work.

**Additional info:**

A [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) solution is completely **not ok**. One of the many many reasons is the following - you manually unlock rows 1 to 10 of a given worksheet and then you lock the whole worksheet. Then you run this code in VBA: `Worksheets("ThatWorksheet").Rows(2).Delete`. Although you are trying to delete the rows that are not locked, you get `1004`. There is a good reason, behind that error, though. It is definitely not a bug.

Comment: Do you have to use data validation for this? If you unlock all the cells in the sheet, lock the formula cells, and then protect the sheet with a blank password, you'll be able to edit all the cells except for those that are locked. If that works for your use case, I'll write it up as a more detailed answer. ([More info on protecting cells](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-75481b72-db8a-4267-8c43-042a5f2cd93a))

Comment: @EngineerToast - Thanks. I am familiar with locking and unlocking cells and sheets. In general, I need data validation, because locking and unlocking these is messing with my VBA. And although it is doable, if I change the VBA code, I do not want to change it, because of this.

Comment: It's a bit hacky but what about a [Worksheet_Change](https://superuser.com/q/1250617/348859) even that just undoes the last operation if certain cells are set to blank? You'd want to change the code on that question from `.Value` to `.Formula` but I think it would work otherwise.

Comment: @EngineerToast - nope, `Worksheet_Change()` is also not ok, I want to make sure that the thing works the way it should work when the macros are disabled. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah. That's the end of my ideas, then. I do not know how to prevent a cell being clear with the DEL key *without* using sheet protection or macros. Data validation only applies when a cell is exited. My best recommendation is still to use protection with no password and add two lines to any code that needs to edit those cells (unprotect and later protect).

Comment: @EngineerToast - unprotect and protect somehow is not enough - if there is a `.Protect` over a worksheet, then an Excel nasty "feature" appears, locking all the unlocked cells by design. And this is against my ideas. Of course, I can go around this as well, changing the `Lock` property and work further, but I am afraid what would happen there. It is easier to change a bit my design and see what would happen.

Comment: If your formulas are all the same using relative references, you might consider using `dynamic named ranges` to at least protect the formulas from being modified.  It won't cause the named formula from being deleted from the cell however.  The solution is to use cell protection and lock the worksheet.

Comment: @wbeard52 - formulas are not the same, quite different, it is a whole worksheet. And with the `=""` from the screenshot the formulas are protected for anything, but being deleted completely.

Answer (score 0):

*If you want to protect all the formula written across sheet (in entire workbook) then you need a pair of VBA Macro.*

**How it works:**

*To speed up the protection/Un-protection better create two command buttons.*

1. From **D**eveloper TAB hit **I**nsert.
2. Form **A**ctiveX controls, select **B**utton Icon and draw on Sheet.
3. Now hit **D**esign.
4. Select button & **R**ight click and from menu hit **P**roperty.
5. From the poped up dialogue find **C**aption and change it to `Protect Formula` (is editable you may set caption of your choice).
6. Now **D**ouble Click the button to reach to VB editor window.
7. **C**opy & **P**aste this code between,

   ```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

     Copy Code here

   End Sub
   ```

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
 With sh
 .Unprotect
 .Cells.Locked = False
 .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Locked = True
 .Protect
  End With
  Next sh

End Sub
```

---

1. Repeat above procedure for **B**utton Two, set Caption `Un-Protect Formula`, and **C**opy & **P**aste this Code.

   ```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    With sh
    .Unprotect
    .Cells.Locked = False
    .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Locked = False
    .Unprotect
     End With
     Next sh

   End Sub
   ```

---

**N.B.**

1. Press **A**lt+Q to return to sheet.
2. Save Workbook as **M**acro Enabled.

*You may work with non VBA method also, but then you need to apply protection Sheet by Sheet, which is time taking job, especially when you have many Sheets in the WB.*

Comment: Hello Rajesh, thank you for your answer, but using VBA for this is really not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Vityata,,, what you are looking for is possible using VBA only,, as I've also written the Non-VBA solution is not so efficient,, and time taking also since It's one Sheet at a time!!